# SSl или TLS сертификат

Tags: ssl, сертификат, tls

Почему используют SSL-сертификаты, если считается, что SSL устаревшая версия протокола и сейчас он заменен на TLS. Почему не употребляется термин TLS-сертификат?

Comment: Может я ошибаюсь, но по-моему именно tls и применяется повсеместно. Просто у него точно такие же сертификаты как ssl

Comment: То есть в сертификатах вообще нет никакого различия, а ssl употребляется потому что просто привыкли?

Comment: `После того, как протокол SSL был стандартизирован IETF (Internet Engineering Task Force), он был переименован в TLS. Поэтому хотя имена SSL и TLS взаимозаменяемы, они всё-таки отличаются, так как каждое описывает другую версию протокола.` https://habrahabr.ru/post/258285/

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться)